# how can i fetch all my photos using FB API for php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am new in Facebook APPS and i want to get all photos that the user has in his account after login

i made the login and the permission well

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/photos' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

when i print the array using `print_r( $graphObject, 1 )`,it gives me long array i got confused

i want fetch the photos only to be able to put it into loop

think like this `echo $graphObject['data']['0']['source'];`

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the result from the API call, you can output the data to your page as:

```
foreach ( $graphObject['data'] as $photo ) {
  echo '<img src="{$photo->images[0]->source}" />';
}
```